# wanted to identify nested array value and replace it

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
{
"_id": "100",
"menu": [
    {
        "type": "1",
        "isenabled": true,
        "items": [
            {
                "key": "activity",
                "enabled": true,
                "criteria": [
                    {
                        "key": "account",
                        "value": [
                            "active"
                        ],
                        "isExclude": false
                    }
                ],
                "eligible": [
                    "QA",
                    "DE"
                ],
                "isItem": false
            }
        ]
    }
```

}

I have below types of docs in a collection.
Here i wanted to identify the value like active and replace that to "inactive" in all docs.
How can we do that in multiple docs at a time.

```
"value": [
          "active"
        ]
```

I tried few things but its not working as expected.

```
db.getCollection('test').update({},
{
  $Set: {"menu.$[m].items.$[i].criteria.$[c].value":["inactive"]}
},
{
  arrayFilters: 
    [
    {
      "m.type":"1"
    },
    {
        "i.key": "activity"
    },
    {
        "c.key": "account"
    }
    ],
  multi: true
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`$set` not `$Set`

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $set: {
    "menu.$[m].items.$[i].criteria.$[c].value": [
      "inactive"
    ]
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "m.type": "1"
    },
    {
      "i.key": "activity"
    },
    {
      "c.key": "account"
    }
  ],
  multi: true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mMtBV8Rkqho)

Comment: My bad. I have changed and it works. But how can we make this change only on the docs where the value is ONLY "active". (Because we have few other values as well which we dont need to change)

Comment: accept this answer and keep your problem in new question

Comment: Thanks. I got this working now.